# Exponential map only for matrix Lie algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Recently, I stumbled over some proofs in Lie algebra theory and noticed that they often use the notion of an exponential map $e^{t \zeta}$ for $\zeta \in \mathfrak{g}$ such that $e^{t \zeta} \in G$ for all t.

Now, I only know how to construt this for matrices (or bounded operators if you wish) as it coincides in this context with the standard exponential map. Despite, many proofs use this construction, so I am not sure if such a map exists for every Lie-algebra. In case that this is true, I would love to know the properties of this map.

In particular, I am interested in knowing more about the differentiability properties of such a map.

Comment: It's more correct to say that this map exists for every Lie *group*, as two groups $G_1, G_2$ whose connected components have the same universal cover have the same Lie algebra $\frak g$, but in general will have distinct exponential maps $\exp: {\frak g} \to G_a$.

Comment: The simplest example entails the unique $1$-dimensional real Lie algebra, which is usually denoted $\Bbb R$, and which we can identify canonically with the Lie algebras of both $(\Bbb R, +)$ and $(\Bbb S^1, \cdot)$. The corresponding exponential maps are
$$\exp: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R,   \qquad \exp(x) = x$$
and, viewing $\Bbb S^1$ as the unit circle in $\Bbb C$,
$$\exp: \Bbb R \to \Bbb S^1, \qquad \exp(x) = e^{i x}.$$
These two exponential maps cannot be identified because, for example, the first is injective but the second is not (it has kernel $2 \pi \Bbb Z$).

Comment: Anyway, the exponential map can indeed be defined for a general Lie group. This is standard material, and a thorough treatment can be found, for example, in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. In any case, "I am interested in knowing more about the differentiability properties of such a map" is probably too broad of a question to be appropriate here; I suggest your post a new, more specific question.